# Configuring a Genius GW-7200 Access Point

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I came across an access point we had a few years ago.
I'm now trying to get it set up to work on our network.

Here are a couple of pictures:

[image]

[image]

I have plugged this into our network via the network port on the back.
I set up a DHCP reservation, based on the MAC address on the back of the access point, however I cannot ping it, nor access the web interface.

I've held down the reset button for 10 seconds, to see if that would do anything.

Google doesn't come up with anything on the matter :-(

Comment: Which port did you use? and are there any blinking lights?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when i get a router of unknown providence i do the following -

1. plug in power (and nothing else). There should be no blinking lights, and nothing should light up other than the power light
2. Plug in a system to the lan port. If its windows, i'll run ipconfig, if its linux ifconfig. I'd note down the default gateway
3. go to the default gateway's ip address to check if the router works.

If it does, then you probably can connect it to an existing wired router by setting a fixed ip address, and connecting the two routers by their *lan* ports.